# how to return to previous form using UINavigation Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

I have used UInavigation controller when the calling form is a UITable but in this case I've used a button to call the form I need using the following code -

```
EditCodesController *editcodesController = [[EditCodesController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditCodesController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *mySocondView =[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                       initWithRootViewController:editcodesController];
[self presentModalViewController: mySocondView animated:YES];
```

This works ok and I've place a 'Back' button on the navigator bar on the form called. What code do I need to use to return to the original form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on the Navigation Bar to dismiss your Modal View Controller. What you need to do is have a selector method in your class where the back button is displayed which calls the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` selector on the original navigation controller

In your opened view, you could have the button set up and the selector like so:

```
 // In viewDidLoad (or similar)
 UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;

 // Your goBack Selector will then be
 - (void)goBack {
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Be aware that this will not work in iOS 5, use `presentingViewController` in iOS 5.

Comment: Fair point @rckoenes, I previously had issues with a modal view not dismissing on older SDK's and using the parent view controller fixed it but i've modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

`[self dismissmodalviewcontroller]` should do the trick for you. But call it in the EditCodesController. Create a delegate and it should work.